# Moving contained liquids vertically

Tags: kinematics

I am wondering how would liquid react if one would put it in a container and move the container on a perfect vertical line (perfect, as in completely vertical with no angle / horizontal shift whatsoever).

E.G taking a glass of water and moving it up and then back down.

On any 'normal' movement of the container, one would observe waves formed on account of the liquid being tossed to one side, but if the movement is perfectly vertical, how can waves form?

Of course the scenario is only hypothetical, since this is probably impossible to reproduce in real life.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical **movement** would cause no extra forces in the container, but the **acceleration** at the top and bottom would cause some very small compression waves in the water.

Think of an elevator.  You only feel lighter and heavier when the elevator is speeding up or slowing down.

Your scenario would be exactly equivalent to a situation where the bottle is stationary but the gravitational acceleration of the Earth is increasing and decreasing.  This is [Einstein's Equivalence Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle).

Assuming that the container is not deforming, only the depth of the water would change slightly as the gravity changes.  In our everyday experience, water is considered incompressible so you wouldn't be able to see this change in the water depth.